# multiple datepicker instances, updating database

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

I'm having an issue submitting a database update using datepicker and I think it has to do with not having unique datepicker instances.

Currently, I'm using a foreach loop (based on a SELECT statement) that builds div sections, each with it's own form that shows current date and a datepicker instance to set a new date.

The datepicker shows up as an input, however, no matter which ones I click it only expands on the first one. I believe this is due to a non-unique name on my datepicker input but I think this is also leading to issues with my ajax and db insert.

Basically, this current loop builds 3 forms at the moment. Each with their own current time label, new time datepicker input, and submit button.

I'm just trying to make it so that if they select a new time for a given page and click submit, it posts to the php script and updates the db with the new time.

I appended the page id `$expiredPage['id']` to the datePicker name which seems ok, but I don't know how to translate that to my $_GET variable in the php script.

Any help here is very much appreciated.

```
<h6>Current Expiration: <?php echo $expiredPage['end_time'] ?></h6>
<br>
<h6>New Expiration: </h6>
<form id="updateTime" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="currentPageID" value="<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>">
  <div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker" name="datePicker<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" />
    <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>

    <input type="submit" name="Extend Date" id="extendDate">
</form>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#extendDate").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var string = $('#updateTime').serialize();

    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "extendTime.php",
            data: string,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
              location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

extendTime.php

```
$pageID = $_GET['currentPageID'];
$newTime = $_GET['datePicker'];

$newEndTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i A', $newTime);
$convertedDateTime = $newEndTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$extendExpiration = "
UPDATE pages 
SET end_time = '$convertedDateTime'
WHERE id = '$pageID';
";

if($mysqlConn->query($extendExpiration)=== TRUE){
 echo "SUCCESS";
}else{
 echo "Could not extend Time";
}

mysqli_close($mysqlConn);
```

Comment: Do you want to submit all the forms at once or the the single form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create only one element on the page with ID, so make the form ID unique to the page and change button `ID` to `CLASS` like below:

```
<form id="updateTime_<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="currentPageID" value="<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>">
  <div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker" name="datePicker<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" />
    <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>

    <input type="submit" name="Extend Date" class="extendDate">
</form>
```

And in you `JS`, do submit the parent form of the clicked button like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".extendDate").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var string = $(this).parent().serialize();

    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "extendTime.php",
            data: string,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
              location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also request type is `POST`, so you will the values in PHP `$_POST`:

```
$pageID = $_POST['currentPageID'];
$newTime = $_POST['datePicker'];
```